# Creating Responsive Website with different ways

Tags: javascript, php, css, responsive-design, media-queries

In order to creating a website that works well in all devices We have some ways:

1. Using CSS frameworks *(like bootstrap)*
2. Using media queries in CSS 3 (old devices / Browsers not supporting media queries)
3. Measurement the size of screen by JavaScript and link to Appropriate CSS file *( **EX**: If the size of user browser width is lower than 400px link to mobile.css  [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24651436/4180321))*
4. Detecting the user browser by HTTP request and redirecting to suitable page *( **EX** : If PHP detected that user Agent is a mobile redirect to a mobile version of that page. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275394/php-script-that-detect-from-user-agent-what-is-the-device-mobile))*

---

**My Questions:**

1-Wich way is better for Great web sites?

2-Is there any other way to creating responsive website?

3-wich way Google, Facebook, Ebay, Amazon are using?

Comment: Check these links, may help you
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/details
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/

Comment: You can combine 1st and 4th way.
We can use bootstrap to support various resolutions(http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bootstrap) and 
we can hide large contents(large grids,...etc) displayed in mobile by detecting user agent using HTTP request.

Comment: Facebook using different view for mobile hosted on its sub domain m.facebook.com. it is light weight, simple and easy to load. so you can use this method (no.3 ) for more accurate responsive website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think google, Facebook and Ebay are uisng  your 4th way, and I think the 4th way is the best way
becouse all user can see the best screen size and the best web page and it is so lite(Small)

Answer (score 2):

*Bootstrap* or any other frameworks (like *PureCSS* or *Metro UI*) is the best way to create responsive websites.

Your 3rd and 4th option will increase the work in recreating the website's pages again for mobile versions. And that too will not be accurate, as nowadays mobile phones have various screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

The best way for creating responsive website is using frameworks and i am recommending to use bootstrap